# SSAS Rowset Action: Replace blank value from DMVs with a text string using MDX

Tags: action, ssas, mdx, olap, rowset

Working in SSAS (inside Visual Studio Shell), I have a rowset action created that returns basic measure information from $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES. Not all measures in the SSAS database have descriptions.

How can I replace BLANK description values with a simple text string "No description available."

```
"select [MEASURE_CAPTION], [MEASUREGROUP_NAME], [MEASURE_DISPLAY_FOLDER],[DESCRIPTION], [EXPRESSION]
from $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES where [MEASURE_UNIQUE_NAME] = '" + Measures].CurrentMember.UniqueName + "'AND [CUBE_NAME] = '" + [Measures].CurrentMember.Properties("CUBE_NAME")  + "'"
```

Returns:

```
Current Measure                 Description
Distinct Person Count
```

DESIRED Return:

```
Current Measure                 Description
Distinct Person Count           No Description Available
```

[Rowset Action Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIYMK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is that just straight `sql` replacement of `null` or is your script returning a string "BLANK" ?

Try replacing `[DESCRIPTION]` with:

```
ISNULL([DESCRIPTION],'No Description Available')
```

or

```
CASE WHEN [DESCRIPTION] = 'BLANK' THEN 'No Description Available' ELSE [DESCRIPTION] END
```

Comment: The rowset actions uses MDX to talk to the SSAS database based on what I've read.